# Java non-persistent but serializable variable

Tags: java, serialization, persistence, transient

In java, how can I declare a variable which is not persistent to a database but it is serializable so that the variable is present in JSON representation of the object containing the variable?

I used the annotation `@javax.persistence.Transient`, but it doesn't work the way I want since `@Transient` variables are not serializable.

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be solved by a specific workaround using modifiers. In order to avoid persisting fields, you have 4 options: marking the field with the modifier *static*, *final* or *transient*; or adding the `@Transient` annotation. Each of these will prevent the field from being persisted into the DB (see [here](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/fields#Transient_Fields)).

Not all these limitations also apply to serialization though. *Static* and *transient* modifiers will prevent serialization, but *final* modifier will not - it will not be persisted but will be serialized (Deserializing in this case is a bit longer, but possible).

I hope this will be applicable to your issue.

Comment: sorry but final fields are not variables. :) Thanks for sharing the knowledge.